# convert a matrix of integers to a column factored matrix with integer values

Tags: r, matrix, r-factor

I have a matrix , all the entries are integers. and the values in columns are discrete. Therefore I want to store them as factors. I have converted each column to factors. But the type of entries now became character. I have found that converting to character is the default. But then I tried what is given in the manual

```
M is the integer matrix

say x <- M[,1]

factor(x,levels=as.integer(x))
```

But this still giving character entries

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Using your test code, I get a factor, not a character.

Comment: ya it is a factor, but the entries are of character data type @thelatemail , I want them to be integer. (I am a newbie to R)

Comment: The whole idea behind factors is to convert vectors of characters into vectors of integers to save memory space. In your case you already have vectors of integers so there is a priori no use for factors.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example

```
set.seed(123)
M <- matrix(sample(1:5,30,replace=TRUE),nrow=5)
x <- M[,1]

# now make a factor - added unique around x to prevent a warning
test <- factor(x,levels=as.integer(unique(x)))
```

This results in:

```
> test
[1] 2 4 3 5 5
Levels: 2 4 3 5

> is.factor(test)
[1] TRUE
> is.character(test)
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(test)
[1] FALSE
> str(test)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "2","4","3","5": 1 2 3 4 4
```

Comment: Oh, my perception that each entry is a character or integer is wrong I think. each entry is of factor data type. I mean data type of test[i] @thelatemail